# Pass item to angular route and open in new view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I start of by calling a method in my MVC-app that returns a list of objects in
`$scope.centrals`:

```
var result = $http.get("/Home/GetCentraler");
    result.success(function (data) {
        $scope.centraler = data;
    });
```

In my main-view I display the items like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in centraler | orderBy:'name' | filter:search" >
    <td class="tdCenter"><img ng-src="{{product.img}}" alt="{{product.name}}" /></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#/products/{{product.id}}"><b>{{product.namn}}</b></a><br />
            {{product.description}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you may see, when I click the `product.name`, I would like to display that item in a specific view.
I must be missing something, I guess I should make a new method in MVC that picks out the object containing the clicked Id. But how can I the pass this object into:

```
<a href="#/products/{{product.id}}"
```

My Routing is set up like this:

```
var storeApp = angular.module('MyAPp', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/store', {
              templateUrl: '/Angular/partials/store.htm',
              controller: storeController
          }).
          when('/products/:Id', {
              templateUrl: '/Angular/partials/product.htm',
              controller: storeController
          }).
          otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/store'
          });
  }]);
```

EDIT1:

When I click the productname-link now, it goes to the correct view but nothing is brought to it.

EDIT2:

```
function storeController($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

    var result = $http.get("/Home/GetCentraler");

    result.success(function(data) {
        $scope.centraler = data;

        function activate() {
            $scope.search = $routeParams;
            if ($routeParams.Id) {
                angular.forEach($scope.centraler, function(item) {
                    if (item.id == $routeParams.Id) {
                        $scope.item = item;
                    }
                })
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see that demo should helps you a bit http://plnkr.co/edit/XyWvKQLuQsegoyG19sg5?p=preview

I can't see definition for storeController in your code and should pass controller name as a string inside route configuration.
Other thing you should have rather different controller for product view and store view

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/store', {
       templateUrl: '/Angular/partials/store.htm',
      controller: 'storeController'
    }).
    when('/products/:Id', {
      templateUrl: '/Angular/partials/product.htm',
      controller: 'storeController'
    }).

    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/store'
    });
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!
I have updated my question with my controller. From what I can understand from the plunker. The way it is now it does not seems like if the loop gets hit.

Comment: sure I can, but my code contains calls to my MVC-app, i´ll add it to plunker anyway, hang on...

Comment: @user2915962 please click fork button first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60892/discussion-between-sss-and-user2915962).